# AND OR order of operations

Tags: operator-precedence

What is the equivalent of this statement?

```
if(cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3 OR cond4 AND cond5 AND cond6)
```

Is it

```
if((cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) OR (cond4 AND cond5 AND cond6))
```

Or

```
if(cond1 AND cond2 AND (cond3 OR cond4) AND cond5 AND cond6)
```

Or

```
if(((cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) OR cond4) AND cond5 AND cond6)
```

ect...

This has been something that I've always been scared approaching, to which I just surround the conditions in parenthesis `( )`. It would be great if my mind could be settled.

Comment: Using parentheses to disambiguate is a great idea.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A good way to remember this is to think of it mathematically.

- `AND` as `*` (multiply)
- `OR` as `+` (addition)
- `TRUE` as `1`
- `FALSE` as `0`

So thinking of it as simple math you get this:

- `0 * 0 = 0`
- `1 * 0 = 0`
- `1 * 1 = 1`
- `0 + 0 = 0`
- `1 + 0 = 1`
- `1 + 1 = 1`

Only thing that may be a tiny bit confusing is `1 + 1 = 1`, but a bit can't go above `1`. But it makes sense if you think of `1` as any non-zero number.

So with this in mind you can then apply this logic:

`if(cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3 OR cond4 AND cond5 AND cond6)`

Becomes:

`if(cond1 * cond2 * cond3 + cond4 * cond5 * cond6)`

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: This is a really cool way to think about boolean operations, and it works as a bonus mnemonic to remember order of ops. Brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: What about `"foo" OR func("bar") AND "baz"`? Even that `AND` has a higher precedence, function isn't invoked at all, because the short-circuiting can happen on `"foo"`. In math operations, short-circuiting doesn't happen, nothing can be skipped, so swapping logical operators to math operators doesn't help I guess.

Answer (score 21):

In most languages `AND` is evaluated first,
hence

```
if((cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) OR (cond4 AND cond5 AND cond 6))
```

is the right choice.

For C#, See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

For C, See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

For Java , See http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php

Comment: _in **most** languages_: in which not?

Comment: There's a list in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages but these are ones that apply a different type of rule (ordering) rather than having different operator precedence for `and` and `or`.

It would be interesting to know how much APL and Smalltalk is still out there being used!

Answer (score 4):

In the normal set of boolean connectives (from a logic standpoint), `and` is higher-precedence than `or`, so `A or B and C` is really `A or (B and C)`.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence) lists them in-order.  Most programming languages should obey this convention unless they are really weird.

That said, for your particular language or environment it should be possible to concoct a very small test to satisfy yourself that it is one way or the other :)

Answer (score 0):

Most languages evaluate AND first.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the language or environment you're asking about, which unfortunately you haven't specified.

`AND` may have higher precedence over `OR`, or it may be the other way around, or it may be equal.

It may be evaluated left-to-right, right-to-left or, from the middle outwards in alternating directions if your language is designed by a sadist :-)

It's quite common for `AND` to have a higher precedence than `OR` and for them both to be left-to-right associative.

In that case

```
cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3 OR cond4 AND cond5 AND cond 6
```

would be equivalent to:

```
((cond1 AND cond2) AND cond3) OR ((cond4 AND cond5) AND cond 6)
```